# CodeIgniter remove index.php in sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to remove the index.php from the url in a codeigniter project thats hosted inside a subdomain 'test'

I've tried the following .htaccess, but I'm getting an internal server error.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

can anyone see the problem, thanks

Comment: just to clarify it's a subfolder 'test', not domain sorry

Answer (score 3):

I use this... should work on a subdfolder as well, I think..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that's very odd. Have you tried it out on a web hosts' server or just localhost?